# Flatten a KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> object using linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

So, basically I'm implementing a MultiMap in C# and I'm taking the obvious approach: using a Dictionary object that uses a List as the value. Next, I need to return a flattened list of key value pairs: `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. It's not so bad to do it using loops, but I'm curious about how to get this done with Linq.

I got close using the SelectMany function, but I couldn't quite figure out how to get from point A to point B. Here's my code that does it without Linq (minus the other bits you don't care about).

```
public class MultiDict<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> _dict = new Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>();

    public void AddValue(TKey key, TValue val)
    {
        List<TValue> list;
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            list = _dict[key];
        }
        else
        {
            list = new List<TValue>();
            _dict.Add(key, list);
        }
        list.add(val);
    }

    public KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] Flattened() 
    {
        var flattened = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
        foreach (var pair in _dict)
        {
            //pair.Value is actually a List<TValue> object that we have to
            //    iterate through as well
            foreach (var val in pair.Value)
            {
                flattened.add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(pair.Key, val));
            }
        }

        return flattened.ToArray();
    }
}
```

So if I used it like this:

```
var multiDict = new MultiDict<int, string>();
multiDict.Add(1, "King");
multiDict.Add(1, "Boomy");
multiDict.Add(3, "Aang");

var results = multiDict.Flattened();
```

I should get three KeyValuePairs in `results`.

Comment: *flatten* == LINQ `SelectMany`

Comment: Have you tried anything in LINQ? There are a number of questions about using LINQ here on SO...

Comment: sigh, it never amazes me how many people don't read the whole question. I mentioned the SelectMany function in my second paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The select many will flatten out the a nested array. The Value.Select creates a KVP for each item in the sublist, the select many then converts the nested array into a flatten collection.

```
public KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] Flattened()
{
    return _dict.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(x.Key, v))).ToArray();
}
```